# Get count vectorizer vocabulary in new dataframe column by applying vectorizer on existing dataframe column using pandas

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have dataframe column 'review' with content like 'Food was Awesome' and I want a new column which counts the number of repetition of each word.

```
name      The First Years Massaging Action Teether
review                    A favorite in our house!
rating                                           5
Name: 269, dtype: object
```

Expecting output like ['Food':1,'was':1,'Awesome':1]
I tried with for loop but its taking too long to execute

```
for row in range(products.shape[0]):
try:        
    count_vect.fit_transform([products['review_without_punctuation'][row]])
    products['word_count'][row]=count_vect.vocabulary_
except:
    print(row)
```

I would like to do it without for loop.

Comment: Why `fit` each row and `transform` that row alone?

Comment: I just gave it a try..I would like to do without for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this.
I have defined a function like this-

```
def Vectorize(text):
try:
    count_vect.fit_transform([text])
    return count_vect.vocabulary_
except:
    return-1
```

and applied above function-

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
products['word_count'] = products['review_without_punctuation'].apply(Vectorize)
```

This solution worked and I got vocabulary in new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count vector for all docs like this:

```py
cv = CountVectorizer()
count_vectors = cv.fit_transform(products['review_without_punctuation'])
```

To get the count vector in array format for a particular document by index, say, the 1st doc,

```py
count_vectors[0].toarray()
```

The vocabulary is in

```py
cv.vocabulary_
```

To get the words that make up a count vector, say, for the 1st doc, use

```py
cv.inverse_transform(count_vectors[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found a solution to do this and posted the answer.